# window.location returns the previous path in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, window.location

I am trying the get the URL of the current page in a TS file in React.

I have something like this

```
export class TrackerClient implements AnalyticsClient {
  private tracker: typeof Tracker;

  sendEvent = ({ category, action, name, value }: sendEventProps): void => {
    console.log('sendEvent', { hash: window.location.hash, location: window.location });
    // Strangely `location` logs the present route and `hash` logs the previous route

    this.tracker = tracker.track({category, action, name, value, url: window.location.hash})
  }
}
```

currently, when sendEvent is called, the following happens

```
currentPage: hash1
currentPage: hash2, location.hash returns hash1
currentPage: hash3, location.hash returns hash2
currentPage: hash4, location.hash returns hash3
```

Please what could be the problem and how can `window.location.hash` log the present route?

Comment: How do you navigate between routes? I guess it shows the current route, you just log to the console before it navigates